# ASP.NET filter dropdown for Repeater Control method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a page (category-list.apsx) that uses the Repeater Control method to display the xml details on the page. I used the example shown here:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

This works fine but I would want the user to be able to filter the results using a dropdown for CategoryName.

The results repeater look like this:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="categories" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryName")%> </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryMonth")%> </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryMonthSpend")%> </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><%#Container.DataItem("Amount")%> </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

The XML look like this:

```
<catalog>
    <categories>
    <CategoryName>Category Name1</CategoryName>
    <CategoryMonth>April 2012</CategoryMonth>
    <CategoryMonthSpend>£1</CategoryMonthSpend> <Amount>1</Amount>                              
    </categories>
</catalog>
```

The script that activates the repeater can be seen below:

```
<script  runat="server">
Public Sub Page_Load()
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim cat As String = Request.QueryString("cat")
        Dim mycategories As DataSet = New DataSet()
        mycategories.ReadXml(MapPath("XML/" + cat + ".xml"))
        categories.DataSource = mycategories
        categories.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: You need a `DropDownList` control to start with. What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: The example in the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) may help you. Change the code in `Index_Changed` to filter the list as appropriate.

Comment: @Jason Would you please post the code that you are using to databind your `Repeater` with?  Also, please include the markup you have defined for your `DropDownList` control.

Comment: I didn't know how to code the DropDownList as it would need to hold the correct CategoryName's that are currently being displayed. So for instance this page may show 20 from Category Name1 and 30 from Category Name10 but none from in between so I would not want the user to be able to select Company Name 2 - 9from the DropDownList.

Comment: @ Mike C - I have added the script that activates the repeater at the bottom of the question

Comment: Also I'm having a bit of difficult understanding your XML.  Is `<categories>` meant to be the root node, or is that what each individual row in your table is wrapped in?

Comment: Sorry Mike I didn't paste in the root in the XML its <catalog>. Its being updated on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, quite a bit to cover here so I won't go into overwhelming detail for each section.  Hopefully this should give you a good starting point to understanding Databinding in ASP.NET a little more.

I prefer actually writing my code in the code-behind, not a `<script runat="server">` inside of my .aspx page, so that's where my code is in this example.  Functionally, however, there is no difference here and you can choose to put this code in that .aspx-side script if you'd prefer.

**First**, let's fix your `Repeater` template.  You appear to be using a table layout, but nowhere in your template is the actual `<table></table>` tag.  You need to add a `<HeaderTemplate>` and a `<FooterTemplate>`

```
<asp:Repeater id="categories" runat="server">    
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryName")%> </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryMonth")%> </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%#Container.DataItem("CategoryMonthSpend")%> </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%#Container.DataItem("Amount")%> </td>
          </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Second**, let's declare a `DropDownList` on your aspx page that you would like to use for filtering:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

The `AutoPostBack` property here means that your `DropDownList` will automatically post back to the server and fire off a `SelectedIndexChanged` event on your server that you can handle in your code.  Alternatively you can use a `Button` to click when you want to trigger the filter.

**Third**, let's separate your databinding code into nice, neat little methods that can more easily be reused.

```
Private Function GetXmlDataSet() As IEnumerable(Of DataRow)

    Dim cat As String = Request.QueryString("cat")
    Dim mycategories As DataSet = New DataSet()

    mycategories.ReadXml(MapPath("XML/" + cat + ".xml"))

    ' I like to use IEnumerable because so that I can use LINQ '
    Return mycategories.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()

End Function

Private Sub BindRepeater(query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
    categories.DataSource = query
    categories.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub BindDropDownList(query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))

    ddlCategory.DataSource = query.Select(Function(x) x("CategoryName")).Distinct()
    ddlCategory.DataBind()

    ' Insert an empty choice into the DropDownList '
    ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, "")

End Sub
```

**Fourth**, let's update your `Page_Load` code so that we can take advantage of these methods:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If (Not IsPostBack) Then

        Dim query = GetXmlDataSet()

        BindDropDownList(query)
        BindRepeater(query)

    End If

End Sub
```

**Last** and certainly not least, let's create the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler in order to trigger filtering of this dataset:

```
Private Sub ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCategory.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selectedCategory As String = ddlCategory.SelectedValue.ToString()

    Dim query = GetXmlDataSet()
    If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCategory)) Then
        query = GetXmlDataSet().Where(Function(x) x("CategoryName") = selectedCategory)
    End If

    BindRepeater(query)

End Sub
```

So what did we do here?  By separating out these databinding methods I made it a little cleaner and allowed the two separate controls to more easily share the same `DataSet` in your XML file.  Using `IEnumerable` allows me to use LINQ which I feel is much nicer than standard querying over `DataTable` or `DataView` objects.

In the `DropDownList` databinding code I am selecting out a single column of your data and turning it into a collection of strings.  I also call `Distinct` for good measure so that duplicates are removed.  I also take the liberty of adding a blank item to the list, so that users have the option to choose NO filter, and display everything.

You'll notice there is a little bit of code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to see if the DropDownList value is blank.  This is not necessarily the most robust (would break down if one of your items actually had a blank "CategoryName" and you wanted to filter on it), but works for this example.  An alternative would be to use `ddlCategory.SelectedIndex <> 0` as a check for if a filter is selected.

This is by no means a complete explanation of everything going on here, so feel free to ask questions.  However this should help get you to a working example that you can expand on for future development.

**Edit:**  This code requires that you have imported the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace and the `System.Linq` namespace.  In Visual Studio 2010, this is likely already automatically imported for you in the Web Application project.  If not, you can choose to add them directly in your code file or on the **Project Properties** page for your web application under **References > Imported Namespaces**

Comment: Thank you for your time Mike! I have updated the code and it has popped up the following error: BC32045: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments. I am guessing I have inserted the code in wrong?

Comment: You may need to import the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: Ok I have added the code at the top <%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %> and have left the other one which was there <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>. It has now jumped to a new error: BC30456: 'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Data.DataRow)'. and its for the line: ddlCategory.DataSource = query.Select(Function(x) x("CategoryName")).Distinct().. Any ideas?

Comment: You will also need `System.Linq`.  I have updated my answer to reflect this, the Web Application Project I use already imports these namespaces globally so this was not required.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it now works a treat! I have more ideas but this is a fantastic start thank you!